# Как выбрать данные из массива дат за каждый час?

Tags: php, sql, datetime

Друзья, в БД хранятся данные на каждые 2 минуты. Я бы хотел создать такой запрос, чтобы я получил только те строки из бд, которые были последними записями за каждый час на текущий момент. Может кто то подсказать как это сделать?

Вот запрос, который, к примеру, выгружает все данные за сегодня:

```
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM core_reservs_status WHERE date > '2016-12-11 00:00:00'");
```

Как его изменить, чтобы были записи только с последними данными на каждый час?

Comment: Сортируй в подзапросе по date DESC так же выбери поле в котором будешь делать группировку по часам т.е. В него должны войти год,месяц,день,час после этого во внешнем запросе сделай группировку по подготовленному полю. Если версия MySQL < 5.7 все должно отработать корректно.

Answer (score 1):

Последние за каждый час - это у которых 58 минут, надо понимать? тогда

```
WHERE ... AND DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%i') = 58
```

А если может быть и 59, то можно >= использовать.

Если же есть "дыры", то получи для каждого часа максимальное время в подзапросе, и по этому подзапросу выполняй отбор.

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать как-то так:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli(host, login, pass, db); //коннектимся к БД
//подготавливаем sql-запрос:
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM core_reservs_status WHERE date > ?"); 

//Получаем текущее время, отмотанное на час назад:
// 1 час * 60 мин. * 60 сек (получаем значение мс):
$date = getdate(time()-1*60*60); 

//функция getdate() возвращает значения в массиве, из них "склеиваем" нашу строку даты:
$current_date = 
$date['year'] . '-' . $date['mon'] . '-' . $date['mday'] . 
$date['hours']. ':' . $date['minutes'] . ':' . $date['seconds']; 

//"привязываем" параметры (строку с нужной датой и временем) к "?":
$stmt -> bind_param('s', $current_date);     

$stmt -> execute(); //выполняем запрос

$result = $stmt -> get_result(); //получаем результат

/*дальше общаетесь с $result как с объектом типа mysqli_result */
```

Здесь используется класс [*mysqli*](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.mysqli.php). Функция [*getdate()*](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.getdate.php).

Comment: 1. Для подкручивания даты вперёд и назад есть функции DATE_ADD и DATE_SUB в MySQL они отработаю гараздо быстрее чем ваши танцы с бубном вокруг php. 2. В задаче необходимо получить строки последние за каждый час, а не как у вас за последний час.